# Does Iron Man 3 have any other Avengers in it?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

Are any of the other Avengers going to be in Iron Man 3? Or is he flying solo?

Comment: This can't really be accurately answered until the movie has been out.

Comment: i have to agree with Tyler, because even if there are any I would assume they would want to keep it a secret

Answer (score 14):

*Marvel Studios* President **Kevin Feige** [said](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=70494) in November 2012:

> ***Iron Man 3* doesn't feature any of the other Avengers**, or Nick Fury showing up, or any of those world-blending conceits that the Phase One films had.
>
> You have to keep in mind that *Iron Man 3* had been in the works for almost a year, year and a half before *The Avengers* was released. We're sticking to the vision for these films, and **showing once again that these characters are just as interesting alone as they are together.**

There was [a rumour](http://screenrant.com/iron-man-3-wasp/) that actress [Stephanie Szostak](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1210895/) was playing [Janet van Dyne](http://marvel.com/universe/Wasp) ***(Wasp)** (she is a founding member of the Avengers in the comics)*.

[image: Wasp]

[According to *Joss Whedon*](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/MarvelFreshman/news/?a=58840) early drafts of *The Avengers* included *Janet van Dyne*

Comment: I think the rumor part of the answer should be removed now because its proven wrong.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I dediced to keep it because it was a prominent rumour, and it provides context to the tidbit about _Janet van Dyne_ being in early drafts of 'The Avengers'.

Comment: Trivia : Stephanie Szostak did appear in Iron Man 3 as [Brandt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/characters/nm1210895?ref_=tt_cl_t9)

Answer (score 12):

Yes - if you wait *right* until the very end of the credits, there's a sequence involving Mark Ruffalo as Bruce Banner. It's just a little joke though and not part of the main plot.

Otherwise, no other Avengers appear.

Answer (score 4):

Samuel L. Jackson said none of the Avengers are gonna be in Iron Man 3.  Here is a source: http://www.whogottherole.com/movie-news/nick-fury-wont-be-needed-in-iron-man-3-24324

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. There is no new avengers in Iron Man 3.

Rumors about [Stephanie Szostak](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1210895/) playing [Janet van Dyne (Wasp)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp_%28comics%29) proved wrong.

She is playing [Ellen Brandt](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ellen_Brandt_%28Earth-616%29) not completely like her comics part and she is given with [Extremis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremis_%28comics%29) virus. Which made her powerful villain not an Avenger. If Ellen Brandt survived somehow(shown killed) then she can be used in Marvel Universe for her connection to [Man-Thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Thing) and [Dr Strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange) but that's all rumor at the moment. For now there is no new Avenger in it.

Bruce Banner's appearance is there after credit but he is not the part of the main story.

Comment: Since someone actually *bunked* their office for IM3, they can answer this for sure ;-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy I didn't bunked office, because i can't ;). so i watched it after office.

Answer (score 4):

I just returned from the showing.

There are no Avengers in the film, but hang around until after the credits if you really want to see another member of the team...

Answer (score 1):

The cast listed on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300854/) doesn't have any members of the Avengers listed.

Comment: It mentions Janet Van Dyne/wasp.

Comment: Missed her, but that's cause she's really small.

Answer (score 0):

No Avengers who were Avengers at the time. However, War Machine/Rhodey does feature prominently. He joins the Avengers in the second recruitment at the end of Age of Ultron.